# UIScrollView: Can I redirect finger scrolling movement from one Scroll view to another?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Sounds a bit complicated. But I have two Scrollviews next to each other. A on the left, B on the right. If I move B, A follows B in a specific manner. Since A is shorter it won't work very nicely vice versa, that's why I don't want to program anything similar that B follows A.

But is it possible that any movement I do with my fingers in scroll view A get passed to Scroll View B, so that actually B scrolls? (And A follows it again of course).

Comment: This is at least the 3rd time you've posted this question. You need to be a bit clearer about what you want to do, and what you've already tried. For example, it's not clear what you want as a result... If the user scrolls (short) scroll view A, should B scroll *faster*? Should B scroll only as far as A can scroll? What about if the user scrolls B to its bottom, and then tries to scroll A? So, try to describe it better -- include images if helpful.

Comment: Sorry yeah these are my tries to get it more clear. I cannot show much more unfortunately. At the moment I've just locked scrollview A so you cannot touch it, but you touch B and A scrolls with it. But my goal is also to touch scrollview A, but that any touch and movement in A triggers the scrollviewDidScroll of B and not A

Comment: Still not clear... the content of `scrollViewA` is not going to be scrolling?

Comment: Only if you scroll scrollViewB. You shouldn't be able to move yourself scrollviewA